# react-native-gesture-handler.addHelper undefined – can't find where the dependency issue is?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm working on a ReactNative app that relies on `react-native-gesture-handler` and I'm trying to integrate `react-native-vision-camera` for a photo taking feature. For the last few days I've been unable to get my app running despite a successful build due to the following error:

```
TypeError: ../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addHelper')
```

I know from the gradle stack trace that the issue is centered in the babel dependencies but I can't track down exactly where, or what the conflict actually is. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Things I've tried so far**

- Removed and re-installed `react-native-gesture-handler`
- Standalone project with only `react-native-vision-camera` installed
- Removed all babel dependencies in package.json (ReactNative and Metro ship with a default implementation as I understand it)
- Cleaned everything, repeatedly
- Attempted deployment on both platforms, same results

Comment: Which version of React Native are you using?

Comment: RN: Version 0.72.1